# React switch themes / css?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a react application that needs to be able to be display in both a light and dark theme.

The two themes I am using are "bootstrap-darkly" and "bootstrap-flatly".

This is what my index.js looks like:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './app';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

// import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

import './bootstrap-darkly.min.css';
import './lib/sb-admin/sb-admin.min.css';
import './lib/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';
import './index.css';

import 'jquery/dist/jquery';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle';

import './prototypes';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Changing the line "import './bootstrap-darkly.min.css';" to "import './bootstrap-flatly.min.css';" achieves the desired result of changing the theme across the application, but I'd like this to be toggled via the UI.

Where / how would the correct approach be to change this via the UI? How can I modify what CSS is imported on that aforementioned line via the UI?

I understand this would probably be best done via a user settings page but am unclear how to make this change using JS.

Comment: Check out: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: I kind of understand the purpose of contexts, but wouldn't this require every component and page element to be modified? Is there no simpler way to just change which theme is being imported?